# Drawing image on Graphics object does not work, but drawing lines work

Tags: java, swing, awt

For some reason painting an image does not appear to work on my Graphics object, please see the Triangle -> paintComponent() method.

Could I be missing something critical? Perhaps to do with not casting the Graphics object to Graphics2D? A transparency mask?

```
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.add(new Triangle());
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(500,500);
    jFrame.repaint();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle extends JPanel {

private int x = 50;
private int y = 50;

private int width = 100;
private int length = 300;

private int direction = 0;

private BufferedImage renderedImage = null;

private Image getRenderedImage() {
    if (renderedImage == null) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        drawGraphics(image.getGraphics());
    }

    return renderedImage;
}

private void drawGraphics(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    // left
    graphics.drawLine(
            (int) Math.round(x - (width / 2.0)), y,
            (int) x, y + length);

    // right
    graphics.drawLine(
            (int) x, y + length,
            (int) Math.round(x + (width / 2.0)), y);

    // bottom
    graphics.drawLine(
            (int) Math.round(x - (width / 2.0)), y,
            (int) Math.round(x + (width / 2.0)), y);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    // this works
    //drawGraphics(graphics);

    // this doesn't work
    graphics.drawImage(getRenderedImage(), 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `BufferedImage image =` try and doing `renderedImage =`. You're returning `renderedImage`, which is null, and that's what's being painted